# Magento CMS Page Translation Issue

Tags: magento, translation

I have 2 store view currently, English and Indonesia
Added 1 page each for English and Indonesia respectively.
See Image 1: 
[image]

See Image 2 :

[image]

On frontend, when I switched the store view, it returns a 404 error page. Any errors in my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404 error Because you have different `URL key`. Once you have URL key same, it will work fine.

Comment: how do I translate then url key then? Because customers in Indonesia might not know what's "About Us"?

Comment: Would anyone able to offer some insight into this?